# WCF with Json and bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, twitter-bootstrap, wcf

I have a simple bootstrap page with a button and when the button is clicked the modal opens up.

the question is the modal content or the modal body should be filled with wcf data, both the webpage and the wcf json data will be hosted in IIS can anyone please help me how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hwAQE.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is to make a ajax call in jquery that will call the WCF method. Below is how you call the service.

```
var Type;
var Url;
var Data;
var ContentType;
var DataType;
var ProcessData;
function WCFJSON() {
    var userid = "1";
    Type = "POST";
    Url = "Service.svc/GetUser";
    Data = '{"Id": "' + userid + '"}';
    ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    DataType = "json"; varProcessData = true; 
    CallService();
}
// Function to call WCF  Service       
function CallService() {
    $.ajax({
        type: Type, //GET or POST or PUT or DELETE verb
        url: Url, // Location of the service
        data: Data, //Data sent to server
        contentType: ContentType, // content type sent to server
        dataType: DataType, //Expected data format from server
        processdata: ProcessData, //True or False
        success: function(msg) {//On Successfull service call
            ServiceSucceeded(msg);
        },
        error: ServiceFailed// When Service call fails
    });
}
function ServiceSucceeded(result) {
if (DataType == "json") {
   $("#ModalBody").html(result)
}
```

Comment: Thank You so much, It is the best self explanatory code.